# MySQL:How to Rewrite a Select element as 'y' then using that later in a where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, mysql-workbench

So what im trying to do is this but this doesn't work:

```
Select count(staffno)as total_staff,avg(salary),branchno
From staff
Where total_staff > 1
Group by branchno
```

Here is another example:

```
Select salary,salary*1.015 as proposed_salary
From staff
Where proposed_salary > 50000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate expression (`sum()`, `count()`, ...) in the `where` clause of the query. This clause is evaluated *before* rows are grouped together by the `group by` clause, so the aggregates are not yet available.

In SQL, that's the purpose of the `having` clause:

```
select count(staffno) as total_staff, avg(salary), branchno
from staff
having count(staffno) > 1 -- MySQL also allows "total_staff > 1"
group by branchno
```

---

As for the second query: the alias defined in the `select` clause is not available in the `where` clause either (for the same reason as above). You can repeat the expression:

```
select salary, salary * 1.015 as proposed_salary
from staff
where salary * 1.015 > 50000
```

Or you can use a derived table (cte or subquery):

```
select *
from (
    select salary, salary * 1.015 as proposed_salary
    from staff
) t
where proposed_salary > 5000
```